# Retrieving Data SQLite Database Issue

Tags: android, sqlite

I create a database containing 4 String columns in a separate class called CalDatabaseHelper:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    updateDatabase(db,0,DATABASE_VERSION);

}

private static void updateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, int olderversion, int newerVersion){
    if (olderversion < 1){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CAL (_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
        + "ACTIVITY1 TEXT, "
        + "ACTIVITY2 TEXT"
        + "ACTIVITY3 TEXT);");
    }
}

private static void insertIntoDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, String primaryKey, String activityOne, String activityTwo, String activityThree){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("_id",primaryKey);
    values.put("ACTIVITY1",activityOne);
    values.put("ACTIVITY2",activityTwo);
    values.put("ACTIVITY3",activityThree);
    db.insert("CAL",null,values);

}
```

I add data in an Activity called Appointments. For now, I just add to the _id (a String variable) and ACTIVITY1 (a String variable that comes from user input into and EditText) columns:

```
                SQLiteOpenHelper sqLiteOpenHelper = new CalDatabaseHelper(Appointments.this);
                SQLiteDatabase db = sqLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                values.put("_id",primaryKey);
                values.put("ACTIVITY1", activityOne);
                db.insert("CAL", null, values);
                db.close();
```

I attempt to retrieve this data in an Adapter Class. Once a widget is clicked, a database is opened, a Cursor finds the two columns(_id, ACTIVITY1) and the data is retrieved. This class contains the primaryKey data that I use to search the database:

```
        SQLiteOpenHelper sqLiteOpenHelper = new CalDatabaseHelper(context);
        db = sqLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        cursor = db.query("CAL",
                new String[]{"_id","ACTIVITY1"},
                "_id = ?",
                new String[]{month_day_year},
                null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            String actOne = cursor.getString(0);
            activityOne.setText(actOne);

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "NOTHING FOUND DURING OPEN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
```

Up until this point, everything works fine. I am able to retrieve the data from the first column (_id) by using cursor.getString(0).

When I go to retrieve the data from the 2nd column (ACTIVITY1), I keep getting an empty String. For example, cursor.getString(1) returns "". This should be the data that my user inputted in my Appointments Activity. The data is clearly placed in to ContentValues within that class and then put in to the database. Any idea why nothing is coming up there? Is it because I am using db.insert() instead of the method I created in my databaseHelper class called insertIntoDatabase()? How come the primary key is inserted then anyway? Thank you

Comment: Please check twice the commas and the spaces in create statement before asking...

Comment: Selvin! What's up man! I did that a few times but no luck. I ended up deleting the table on a downgrade and recreated it on an upgrade. It seems to be working fine now

Comment: Hmm in the question you forgot about ", " after 3rd column

Comment: Whoa, great catch! That'll save me a headache when trying to insert into that third column